# PowerBI access to progress tables in pdf files

Tags: pdf, powerbi

I was given a task to access monthly report data that are stored in pdf files with the same structure where each month lists cost, progress, manpower and a lot of statistics.

I am able to access a single pdf file and get those numbers for a given month, but I am struggling to access all reports (12 for a year) and extract information to display variations within the year such as cost and progress increase and more statistics.

Is there a way to achieve this in PowerBI? If the individual tables don't contain information about the month in question, is it possible to extract that from the filename (`March-2021-report.pdf` for example)?

Comment: Power BI is not a database management system. You should build an ETL process to extract the data from these PDF files (or better from the data source directly), then to load it in a data warehouse or something, and only after that to use Power BI to build reports over this new data source.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is uploading all the PDF's of a folder at a shot then you should be placing all those PDF's in a folder and select the folder from GET DATA option.[image]

Once done you should be able to play around with the PDF data.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My point is how to extract tabular data from those pdf files (they have a similar template) into PowerBI to display various statistics about costs and progress.